# Vector bundles over curves

Tags: algebraic-geometry, curves, sheaf-theory, vector-bundles

On page 5 of "[Mixed twistor structures](https://arxiv.org/abs/alg-geom/9705006)", C. Simpson writes

> Recall that a strict subsheaf of a vector bundle over a curve is determined by its restriction to any
> Zariski open set

How is this true? Firstly, every vector bundle $E$ is a strict subsheaf of another vector bundle, just take $E \oplus \mathcal O_C$, for $C$ the curve. Therefore I'm confused by his insistence on strictness.

Now if we take a trivialising open cover $\{U_i\}$ of the curve $C$ for the vector bundle $E$ and restrict $E$ to $U_i$, how could this determine $E$ uniquely?

Once my confusion has been cleared up, I would like to know if there are related results for higher-dimensional (projective) varieties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most probably what Simpson means is that a strict subsheaf of a **fixed** vector bundle is determined by its restriction to any **nonempty** Zariski open set. Indeed, if $E$ is the fixed vector bundle, $j \colon U \to C$ is the embedding of a nonempty Zariski open set, and $F \subset j^*E$ is a strict subsheaf, extend the embedding to an exact sequence
$$
0 \to F \to j^*E \to G \to 0
$$
and define
$$
\tilde{F} := \operatorname{Ker}(E \to j_*G),
$$
where the morphism $E \to j_*G$ is the adjoint of $j^*E \to G$. Then $\tilde{F} \subset E$ is the strict subsheaf in $E$ determined by $F \subset j^*E$.

Comment: I see! Thanks very much for the quick answer. Is there any reason this wouldn't hold for $C$ an arbitary scheme?

Comment: Sorry but  I think this answer is wrong. you didn't prove that every subsheaf of the vector bundle come from such a construction and I don't think this is true in general.

Comment: @ali: The crucial step is that if $E \to \tilde{G}$ is an epimorphism to a **torsion free** sheaf, then the morphism $E \to j_*j^*\tilde{G}$ adjoint to the restriction $j^*E \to j^*\tilde{G}$ of the original epimorphism factors through the **injective** morphism $\tilde{G} \to j_*j^*\tilde{G}$, hence its kernel is equal to the kernel of $E \to \tilde{G}$.

Comment: just take any vector bundle $E$ other than $O_C$, take two independent global section of $E$ like $f,g$, and let $F_1$ be the subsheaf of $E$ generated by $f$ and $F_2$ be the subsheaf generated by $f,g$  then on the Zariski open subset $U$ that $E$ is trivial then $F_1=F_2=E$ but clearly $F_1\not=F_2$. in general

Comment: @ali: What you probably mean is that $F_1 \cong F_2$ as abstract sheaves. But they are different as subsheaves of $E$!

Comment: no they are the same because over $U$ the section $f$(or any other section) generates the whole sheaf!. just to be clear I claim they are the same over $U$ but not the same globally which means that your claim can not be true

Comment: @ali: But $f$ and $g$ are different sections of $E$, so they generate different subsheaves in $E$.

Comment: Just take $E=O(1),f=x,g=y$ over D(x) you have $<x>_{|D(x)}=<x,y>_{|D(x)}=O(1)_{|D(x)}$ because $x$ generates $O(1)$,like you say over $P^1$ x and y generates different subsheaves. so you have two different subsheave that agree on a Zariski open!. i think you just need a moment to think about it.

Comment: @ali: If $E$ is of rank 1 then $E/F_1$ and $E/F_2$ are not torsion free, which in the terminology of Simpson (I guess) means $F_1$ and $F_2$ are not strict subsheaves (though usually this property is called saturatedness), so this example does not satisfy the assumptions.

Comment: Ok thanks I was not aware of the notation

Answer (score 0):

In general if you have an open immersion $j:U\subset X$ and a closed immersion $i:Z\to X$ sich that $X=Z\cup U$,then giving a sheaf $F$ over $X$ is the same as giving a triple $F_1,F_2,\phi$ where $F_1$ is a sheaf over $U$,$F_2$ is a sheaf over $Z$ and $\phi$ is a morphism $\phi:F_2\to i^*j_* F_1$. I learn this from page 73 of Milne book on etale cohomology but this should be pretty standard.

Now back to the problem, in the case you want, you have a fixed vector bundle $E$ and a Zariski open $U$, because $C$ is a curve $C-U$ is union of some points so $i^* E$ is a trivial bundle.so $F_2$ should be a trivial bundle with a rank smaller than $E$. this show that in general $F\subset E$ can not determined by restriction of $F$ to the $U$(which we called $F_1$) because you have different choices for $F_2$. but if you want $F$ to be a sub-vectorbundle then the rank of $F_2$ should be equal to the rank of $F_1$ so $F_1$ determines $F_2$ and $\phi_F$ is determanined by $\phi_E$. In summary the true statement is this:

a Sub-vector bundle of a vector bundle $E$ over a curve $C$ is determined by its restriction to any open Zariski subset.